# java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, ibm-was, linkageerror

I getting error below while deploying the Web service war file in Websphere 7. This web service war file is created using Axis2 and contain a Very basic Service (Hello World!). Can some one point me what could be issue?

> [6/25/14 17:10:42:132 IST] 0000000f SystemOut     O [ERROR] loading constraint violation: loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@679e679e" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPFactory" defined by loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@71817181"
>   java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation: loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@679e679e" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPFactory" defined by loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@71817181"
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:160)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:550)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:520)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:451)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:430)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:417)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:334)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:386)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:347)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:83)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
>       at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:154)
>       at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.(RampartMessageData.java:270)
>       at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:60)
>       at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the this article which has details about running Axis2 and resolving error in Websphere with Axis2

http://zacktutorials.blogspot.ca/2014/04/axis2-installation-in-websphere-80-to.html

Problem: java.lang.VerifyError: class loading constraint violated (class: org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl method: getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration;) at pc: 0

Solution : (FIX for "java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated" )

In the xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar à remove org.dom package

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249